# How can I  extract the meaning of a paragraph?

Tags: ruby, regex, rubygems

I need to develop method that extracts the meaning from a string for a record in a database. Here is an example of the a string:

```
MyString = "Purse $75,000. (up To $14,250 Nysbfoa) For Maidens, Fillies And Mares Three Years Old And Upward. Three Year Olds, 118 Lbs.; Older, 123 Lbs. One And One Eighth Miles. (Inner turf)"
```

Given the string, I need to process it in such a way that I can create a race_record:

```
race_record[:purse] = 75000 
race_record[:race_type] = "Maidens"
race_record[:sex] = "Fillies And Mares"
race_record[:age] = "Three Year Old And Upward"
race_record[:distance] = "One And One Eighth Miles"
race_record[:surface] = "inner turf"
```

I was planning on to use ruby and a series of regular expressions to extract the data. For example:

```
race_record[:purse] = Mystring.scan(/(?<=\Purse\s[$])(.*?)(?=\.)/)
race_record[:race_type] = Mystring.sub(....)
etc.
```

My question isn't so much what the correct regular expressions are. Given the objective, is the approach I proposed the right way to go, or is there a better approach or even a gem that can do the heavy lifting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one regex to extract all the relevant parts into capturing groups at once;

```
regexp = 
    /Purse\s\$          # Leading text
    ([\d,]+)            # Group 1
    .*?For\s            # Intervening text
    (\w+)               # Group 2
    ,\s                 # Intervening text
    (\w+\sAnd\s\w+)     # Group 3, etc. etc.
    \s
    ([^.]*)
    \.[^;]*;[^.]*\.\s
    ([^.]*)
    \.\s\(
    ([^()]*)
    \)/x
```

Then you can do

```
irb(main):025:0> match = regexp.match(mystring)
=> #<MatchData "Purse $75,000. (up To $14,250 Nysbfoa) For Maidens, Fillies And    Mares Three Years Old And Upward. Three Year Olds, 118 Lbs.; Older, 123 Lbs. One And One Eighth Miles. (Inner turf)" 
   1:"75,000" 2:"Maidens" 3:"Fillies And Mares" 4:"Three Years Old And Upward" 
   5:"One And One Eighth Miles" 6:"Inner turf">
irb(main):026:0> match[1]
=> "75,000"
irb(main):027:0> match[2]
=> "Maidens"
...etc.
```

Comment: Tim - Thanks for the response. That's just the sort of thing I was looking for. If I can make elements of a capturing group optional this may do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: To man a capturing group "optional", quantify it with "?" (o or 1), i.e. ...(somestuff)?... The upside of using several different smaller REs (rather than one big RE) is there's no requirement the text be in the right _order_. You know your data - can you assume that if the data's there at all, it will be in the canonical order?

Answer (score 1):

If your input is fairly structured,  i.e. it has a specific and know grammar,  you could build a 'parser' to parse the grammar.

In the old days, we'd do this with yacc and lex,  two old unix tools used to build compilers.  Yacc and Lex have Ruby implementations.  While the original intent was to output lower level code (such as machine assembly codes when building a real compiler),  there is nothing that prevents you from calling any ruby code when a specific grammatical construct has been recognized by your parser.

NOTE:  even though there is a Yacc/lex Ruby gem out there,  I wouldn't say it will 'DO THE HEAVY LIFTING',  learning yacc and lex has a small learning curve.   Using something like yacc/lex would make your life easier in the long run,  especially if you have a large grammar and must constantly adjust it.

Comment: Another parser for Ruby is Treetop, a Parsing Expression Grammar (PEG).  A PEG is lighter weight than yacc/lex, yet adequate for many grammars.

Comment: @Wayne Conrad 
probably better,  yacc/lex WAS originally intended for the very complex grammars associated with programming languages.  If Treetop was designed from the get go for simple 'human readable' grammars,  it's probably the ticket.  Again assuming your input has a fixed grammar you can depend on.